# How to count by binning in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have sample data like

```
age year  score
0  2018    10
7  2019    20
11 2018    30
13 2019    40
14 2018    50
```

I would like to bin like

```
count       
       year 
age    2018  2019
0-4     1     0
5-9     0     1
10-14   2     1
15-19   0     0
```

And I would like to sum up score like

```
total score      
       year 
age    2018  2019
0-4     10    0
5-9     0     20
10-14   80    40
15-19   0     0
```

I tried.but it couldn't work well,Afterward I tried pivoting by spreadsheet.

How can I transform like above by using SQL?

Comment: That should be 80 40 for 10-14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `connect by level` expressions joining with your table through the contribution of `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
with tab_age as
(
 select min(level-1) as age1, max(level-1) as age2
   from dual
connect by level <= 20
  group by floor((level-1)/5)
), tab(age,year,score) as
(
 select 0 , 2018, 10 from dual union all
 select 7 , 2019, 20 from dual union all
 select 11, 2018, 30 from dual union all
 select 13, 2019, 40 from dual union all
 select 14, 2018, 50 from dual  
), tab2 as
(
select t2.age1, t2.age2, 
       count( case when t1.year=2018 then 1 end ) as "2018",
       count( case when t1.year=2019 then 1 end ) as "2019"
  from tab t1
  right join tab_age t2 on t1.age between t2.age1 and t2.age2
 group by t2.age1, t2.age2  
 order by t2.age1, t2.age2  
) 
select concat(concat(age1,'-'),age2) as age,
       "2018", "2019"
  from tab2;

AGE     2018    2019
0-4     1       0
5-9     0       1
10-14   2       1
15-19   0       0
```

and

```
with tab_age as
(
 select min(level-1) as age1, max(level-1) as age2
   from dual
connect by level <= 20
  group by floor((level-1)/5)
), tab(age,year,score) as
(
 select 0 , 2018, 10 from dual union all
 select 7 , 2019, 20 from dual union all
 select 11, 2018, 30 from dual union all
 select 13, 2019, 40 from dual union all
 select 14, 2018, 50 from dual  
), tab2 as
(
select t2.age1, t2.age2, 
       sum( case when t1.year=2018 then score else 0 end ) as "2018",
       sum( case when t1.year=2019 then score else 0 end ) as "2019"
  from tab t1
  right join tab_age t2 on t1.age between t2.age1 and t2.age2
 group by t2.age1, t2.age2  
 order by t2.age1, t2.age2  
) 
select concat(concat(age1,'-'),age2) as age,
       "2018", "2019"
  from tab2;

 AGE    2018    2019
 0-4    10      0
 5-9    0       20
 10-14  80      40
 15-19  0       0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5fb1029cab18834ed366f9dd7b1b7253)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to turn the ages into their "age group" by taking advantage of integer math (ie. 7/5 is 1). Then create the 2018 and 2019 columns using a case statement.

```
select
  age/5*5 as age_group_lower,
  case year
  when 2018 then
    score
  end as "2018",
  case year
  when 2019 then
    score
  end as "2019"
from scores;

age_group_lower  2018  2019
0                10     
5                      20
10               30     
10                     40
10               50
```

This can the be used in a CTE and summed as you like.

```
with score_years as (
    select
      age/5*5 as age_group_lower,
      case year
      when 2018 then
        score
      end as "2018",
      case year
      when 2019 then
        score
      end as "2019"
    from scores
)
select
  age_group_lower || '-' || age_group_lower + 4 as age_group,
  sum("2018") as "2018", sum("2019") as "2019"
from score_years
group by age_group_lower
order by age_group_lower;

age_group   2018    2019
0-4         10  
5-9                 20
10-14       80      40
```

This is in Postgres syntax (sorry, I don't know Oracle), but there's nothing here which Oracle shouldn't be able to handle.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f7c4fc7bdb5d0b9dd7338c0b2794fa70)

Comment: I really like this approach.  However, the last age group (15-19) is missing from the result set.

Comment: @stefan In Postgres I'd use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to create the list of age groups and join against it. Don't know if Oracle has an equivalent.

Comment: You'd probably use "select ... connect by level ..." (see Barbaros's solution) - there's no "generate series" in Oracle AFAIK.

Comment: Also: "select 7/5 from dual" returns 1.4 (no SELECT without FROM  in Oracle) - so I used TRUNC() when retracing your steps.  And: concatenating age_group_lower with '-' causes an "invalid number" error.  Thus, I used TO_CHAR().  See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01f8882b4e07864eea3164145b2d8f94